# how to determine base of a number?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, numbers

Given a integer number and its reresentation in some arbitrary number system. The purpose is to find the base of the number system. For example, number is 10 and representation is 000010, then the base should be 10. Another example: number 21 representation is 0010101 then base is 2. One more example is: number is 6 and representation os 10100 then base is sqrt(2). Does anyone have any idea how to solve such problem?

Comment: Simple. All numbers are base 10.

Comment: A number of solutions (to great to comment on them all) have treated this as a general polynomial equation... ignoring a very special constraint of the base systems: for any `I`, `base^I > ∑(i in [0, I[)(digit[i] * base^i)`. This property makes it much easier, I've illustrated it in an answer because I lacked the place for equations here but it does considerably simplify the problem at hand.

Comment: @slacker: I prefer base 16, myself.

Comment: Solutions to this problem might take very different approaches depending on whether they can be limited to integer bases.  You question implies you wan the general case, but do you really need the answer to be so general?

Comment: @Hasturkun:
You obviously didn't get the joke.

Comment: Yes i solved it. But still it has some problems, i'll post tomorrow.

Comment: @Matthieu: I don't think that inequality can be inferred from what is in the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An algorithm like this should find the base if it is an integer, and should at least narrow down the choices for a non-integer base:

- Let `N` be your integer and `R` be its representation in the mystery base.
- Find the largest digit in `R` and call it `r`.

  - You know that your base is at least `r + 1`.
- For `base == (r+1, r+2, ...)`, let `I` represent `R` interpreted in base `base`

  - If `I` equals `N`, then `base` is your mystery base.
  - If `I` is less than `N`, try the next base.
  - If `I` is greater than `N`, then your base is somewhere between `base - 1` and `base`.

It's a brute-force method, but it should work.  You may also be able to speed it up a bit by incrementing `base` by more than one if `I` is significantly smaller than `N`.

Something else that might help speed things up, particularly in the case of a non-integer base:  Remember that as several people have mentioned, a number in an arbitrary base can be expanded as a polynomial like

```
x = a[n]*base^n + a[n-1]*base^(n-1) + ... + a[2]*base^2 + a[1]*base + a[0]
```

When evaluating potential bases, you don't need to convert the entire number.  Start by converting only the largest term, `a[n]*base^n`.  If this is larger than `x`, then you already know your base is too big.  Otherwise, add one term at a time (moving from most-significant to least-significant).  That way, you don't waste time computing terms after you know your base is wrong.

Also, there is another quick way to eliminate a potential base.  Notice that you can re-arrange the above polynomial expression and get

```
(x - a[0]) = a[n]*base^n + a[n-1]*base^(n-1) + ... + a[2]*base^2 + a[1]*base
```

or

```
(x - a[0]) = (a[n]*base^(n-1) + a[n-1]*base^(n-2) + ... + a[2]*base + a[1])*base
```

You know the values of `x` and `a[0]` (the "ones" digit, you can interpret it regardless of base).  What this gives you the extra condition that `(x - a[0])` must be evenly divisible by `base` (since all your `a[]` values are integers).  If you calculate `(x - a[0]) % base` and get a non-zero result, then `base` cannot be the correct base.

Comment: Thanks, i am using a similar approach, but in a different manner, see i'll. Post tomorrow.

Comment: You suppose that `base` is an integer (in which case the problem is trivial)... I made the same error, but `@evil.coder` has given an example where `base` is `sqrt(2)`.

Comment: @Matthieu M.- In the case of a non-integer base, this algorithm will shrink your search space to the interval between two adjacent integers.  Once you know these bounds, you can do a binary search within that range to further narrow down your base.  However, if your base is an irrational number, this process will never converge.

Answer (score 12):

```
         ___
         \
number = /__ ( digit[i] * base ^ i )
```

You know `number`, you know all `digit[i]`, you just have to find out `base`.

Whether solving this equation is simple or complex is left as an exercise.

Comment: You are ignoring some fundamental properties of the base system in the magnitude of the terms to sum. For any `I`, `base^I > ∑(i = 0; i < I; ++i)(digit[i] * base^i)`.

Answer (score 8):

I do not think that an answer can be given for every case. And I actually have a reason to think so! =)

Given a number x, with representation `a_6 a_5 a_4 a_3 a_2 a_1` in base b, finding the base means solving

```
a_6 b^5 + a_5 b^4 + a_4 b^3 + a_3 b^2 + a_2 b^1 + a_1 = x.
```

This cannot be done generally, as shown by [Abel and Ruffini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem). You might be luckier with shorter numbers, but if more than four digits are involved, the formulas are increasingly ugly.

There are quite a lot good approximation algorithms, though. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm).

Comment: Still, as the floating-point types have a limited precision, this is solvable numerically.

Comment: Only if you know that the base can be represented as a float. Most bases can't.

Comment: +1 I'm quite certain that in the second example in the question, the base is actually -sqrt(2).  I have no idea where the asker lost the minus sign, but...

Comment: In which case the goal is to find the float closest to the correct answer... slacker is right.

Answer (score 6):

For integers only, it's not that difficult (we can enumerate).

Let's look at `21` and its representation `10101`.

```
1 * base^4 <= 21 < (1+1) * base^4
```

Let's generate the numbers for some bases:

```
base   low   high
2      16    32
3      81    162
```

More generally, we have `N` represented as ∑ a<sub>i</sub> * base<sup>i</sup>. Considering `I` the maximum power for which a<sub>I</sub> is non null we have:

```
a[I] * base^I <= N < (a[I] + 1) * base^I  # does not matter if not representable

# Isolate base term
N / (a[I] + 1) < base^I <= N / a[I]

# Ith root
Ithroot( N / (a[I] + 1) ) < base <= Ithroot( N / a[I] )

# Or as a range
base in ] Ithroot(N / (a[I] + 1)), Ithroot( N / a[I] ) ]
```

In the case of an integer base, or if you have a list of known possible bases, I doubt they'll be many possibilities, so we can just try them out.

Note that it may be faster to actually take the `Ithroot` of `N / (a[I] + 1)` and iterate from here instead of computing the second one (which should be close enough)... but I'd need math review on that gut feeling.

If you really don't have any idea (trying to find a floating base)... well it's a bit more difficult I guess, but you can always refine the inequality (including one or two more terms) following the same property.

Comment: One of asker's examples has the base to be found as sqrt(2).

Comment: Since all digits are strictly non-negative, if the base is also assumed non-negative, then it's a convex optimization problem with a unique solution.  You've described some good and easily found bounds, binary search (possibly with interpolation instead of equal bisection) can take it from there.

Comment: @Matthieu: Get rid of the floor and ceil and you'll be fine with non-integral numbers, as AakashM points out are needed.

Comment: I did not realized it... did not do maths of this level for a while oO

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is efficiently solvable. I would just try to pick a random base, see if given the base the result is smaller, larger or equal to the number. In case its smaller, pick a larger base, in case its larger pick a smaller base, otherwise you have the correct base.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a starting point:

Create an equation from the number and representation, number 42 and represenation "0010203" becomes:

```
1 * base ^ 4 + 2 * base ^ 2 + 3 = 42
```

Now you solve the equation to get the value of `base`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you will need try and check different bases. To be efficient, your starting base could be max(digit) + 1 as you know it won't be less than that. If that's too small double until you exceed, and then use binary search to narrow it down. This way your algorithm should run in O(log n) for normal situations.

Answer (score 1):

Several of the other posts suggest that the solution might be found by finding the roots of the polynomial the number represents.  These will, of course, generally work, though they will have a tendency to produce negative and complex bases as well as positive integers.

Another approach would be to cast this as an integer programming problem and solve using branch-and-bound.

But I suspect that the suggestion of guessing-and-testing will be quicker than any of the cleverer proposals.

Comment: The question shows an example of non-integral base.  Hence integer programming isn't applicable.